Is there a reason I can't collect data from my nested React form
I am working on a NextKs app, currently working on a component that has a form. Some of the key/value pair on the form are nested (please see the code below). I was under the impression that I can traverse down element on the form, but somehow getting errors
import React from "react";

const Rafce = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    title: "",
    objectives: "",
    demographic: {
      geographic: {
        country: "",
        state: "",
        city: "",
      },
      target: "",
      gender: "",
      age: "",
      intention: "",
    },
    campaignReason: "",
    strategy: "",
  });


  const items = [
    "Item 1",
    "Item 2",
    "Item 3",
    "Item 4",
    
  ];

  const profession = ["Yes|No", "Yes", "No"];

  //Handling Country selection
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
  const [states, setStates] = useState([]);
  const [cities, setCities] = useState([]);

  const [selectedCountry, setSelectedCountry] = useState("");
  const [selectedState, setSelectedState] = useState("");
  const [selectedCity, setSelectedCity] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    setCountries(Country.getAllCountries());
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedCountry) {
      setStates(State.getStatesOfCountry(selectedCountry));
      setCities([]); // Reset cities when country changes
    }
  }, [selectedCountry]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedState) {
      setCities(City.getCitiesOfState(selectedCountry, selectedState));
    }
  }, [selectedState, selectedCountry]);

  const handleCountryChange = (event) => {
    setSelectedCountry(event.target.value);
    setSelectedState("");
    setSelectedCity("");
  };

  const handleStateChange = (event) => {
    setSelectedState(event.target.value);
    setSelectedCity("");
  };

  const handleCityChange = (event) => {
    setSelectedCity(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };


  return (<div>
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className="space-y-12">
        <div className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-x-8 gap-y-10 border-b border-gray-900/10 pb-12 md:grid-cols-3">
          <div>
            <h2 className="text-base font-semibold leading-7 text-gray-900">
              Some Name
            </h2>
          </div>

          <div className="grid max-w-2xl grid-cols-1 gap-x-6 gap-y-8 sm:grid-cols-6 md:col-span-2">
            <div className="col-span-full">
              <label
                htmlFor="title"
                className="block text-sm font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900"
              >
               Company Title
              </label>
              <div className="mt-2">
                <div className="flex rounded-md shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 focus-within:ring-2 focus-within:ring-inset focus-within:ring-red-600 sm:max-w-md">
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    name="title"
                    id="title"
                    value={formData.title}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    className="block flex-1 w-full border-0 bg-transparent py-1.5 pl-1 text-gray-900 placeholder:text-gray-400 focus:ring-0 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6"
                    placeholder="Your organization name"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            
            <div className="relative inline-block text-left z-50 col-span-full">
              <select
                value={selectedItem}
                onChange={(e) => setSelectedItem(e.target.value)}
              >
                <option value="Select Type" disabled>
                  Select  Type
                </option>
                {items.map((item, index) => (
                  <option key={index} value={item}>
                    {item}
                  </option>
                ))}
              </select>
            </div>
            <div className="col-span-full">
              <label
                htmlFor="objectives"
                className="block text-sm font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900"
              >
                Objectives
              </label>
              <div className="mt-2">
                <textarea
                  id="objectives"
                  name="objectives"
                  value={formData.objectives}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  rows={3}
                  className="block w-full rounded-md border-0 py-1.5 text-gray-900 shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 placeholder:text-gray-400 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-red-600 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6"
                  defaultValue={""}
                  placeholder="What are the specific goals of the campaign beyond just raising funds? (e.g., increasing awareness, engaging new donors)"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-span-full">
              <label
                htmlFor="features"
                className="block text-sm font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900"
              >
                Defining demographics
              </label>
              <div className="mt-2">
                <div className="isolate -space-y-px rounded-md shadow-sm">
                  <div className="relative rounded-md rounded-t-none px-3 pb-1.5 pt-2.5 ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 focus-within:z-10 focus-within:ring-2 focus-within:ring-red-600">
                    <label
                      htmlFor="feature02"
                      className="block text-xs font-medium text-gray-900"
                    >
                      Geographic location
                    </label>
                    <div className="mb-3">
                      <label
                        className="block text-xs font-medium text-gray-900"
                        htmlFor="country"
                      >
                        Country:{" "}
                      </label>
                      <select
                        id="country"
                        value={selectedCountry}
                        onChange={handleCountryChange}
                      >
                        <option
                          className="block text-xs font-medium text-gray-900"
                          value=""
                        >
                          Select Country
                        </option>
                        {countries.map((country) => (
                          <option key={country.isoCode} value={country.isoCode}>
                            {country.name}
                          </option>
                        ))}
                      </select>
                    </div>

                    {states.length > 0 && (
                      <div className="mb-3">
                        <label
                          className="block text-xs font-medium text-gray-900"
                          htmlFor="state"
                        >
                          State:{" "}
                        </label>
                        <select
                          id="state"
                          value={selectedState}
                          onChange={handleStateChange}
                        >
                          <option
                            className="block text-xs font-medium text-gray-900"
                            value=""
                          >
                            Select State/Region
                          </option>
                          {states.map((state) => (
                            <option key={state.isoCode} value={state.isoCode}>
                              {state.name}
                            </option>
                          ))}
                        </select>
                      </div>
                    )}
                    {cities.length > 0 && (
                      <div className="mb-3">
                        <label
                          className="block text-xs font-medium text-gray-900"
                          htmlFor="city"
                        >
                          City:{" "}
                        </label>
                        <select
                          id="city"
                          value={selectedCity}
                          onChange={handleCityChange}
                        >
                          <option
                            className="block text-xs font-medium text-gray-900"
                            value=""
                          >
                            Select City
                          </option>
                          {cities.map((city) => (
                            <option key={city.name} value={city.name}>
                              {city.name}
                            </option>
                          ))}
                        </select>
                      </div>
                    )}
                  </div>
                  <div className="relative rounded-md rounded-t-none px-3 pb-1.5 pt-2.5 ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 focus-within:z-10 focus-within:ring-2 focus-within:ring-red-600">
                    <label
                      htmlFor="target"
                      className="block text-xs font-medium text-gray-900"
                    >
                      Target
                    </label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      name="target"
                      id="target"
                      value={formData.demographic.target}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                      className="block w-full border-0 p-0 text-gray-900 placeholder:text-gray-400 focus:ring-0 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6"
                      placeholder="e.g: Gen Z, Baby Boomers, Gen X"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="relative rounded-md rounded-t-none px-3 pb-1.5 pt-2.5 ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 focus-within:z-10 focus-within:ring-2 focus-within:ring-red-600">
                    <label
                      htmlFor="gender"
                      className="block text-xs font-medium text-gray-900"
                    >
                      Gender
                    </label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      name="gender"
                      id="gender"
                      value={formData.demographic.gender}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                      className="block w-full border-0 p-0 text-gray-900 placeholder:text-gray-400 focus:ring-0 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6"
                      placeholder="E.g: 'Male' or 'Female' "
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="relative rounded-md rounded-t-none px-3 pb-1.5 pt-2.5 ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 focus-within:z-10 focus-within:ring-2 focus-within:ring-red-600">
                    <label
                      htmlFor="age"
                      className="block text-xs font-medium text-gray-900"
                    >
                      Age
                    </label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      name="age"
                      id="age"
                      value={formData.demographic.age}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                      className="block w-full border-0 p-0 text-gray-900 placeholder:text-gray-400 focus:ring-0 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6"
                      placeholder="e.g: 20-64"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="relative rounded-md rounded-b-none px-3 pb-1.5 pt-2.5 ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 focus-within:z-10 focus-within:ring-2 focus-within:ring-red-600">
                    <label
                      htmlFor="intention"
                      className="block text-xs font-medium text-gray-900"
                    >
                     Intention
                    </label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      name="intention"
                      value={formData.demographic.intention}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                      id="intention"
                      className="block w-full border-0 p-0 text-gray-900 placeholder:text-gray-400 focus:ring-0 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6"
                      placeholder="e.g: Events"
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-span-full">
              <label
                htmlFor="features"
                className="block text-sm font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900"
              >
                Strategy
              </label>
              <div className="mt-2">
                <div className="isolate -space-y-px rounded-md shadow-sm">
                  <div className="relative rounded-md rounded-b-none px-3 pb-1.5 pt-2.5 ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 focus-within:z-10 focus-within:ring-2 focus-within:ring-red-600">
                    <label
                      htmlFor="feature01"
                      className="block text-xs font-medium text-gray-900"
                    >
                      What strategies have you tried
                    </label>
                    <div className="flex justify-between">
                      <Select
                        label=""
                        placeholder="Click to Select (multiple if needed)"
                        selectionMode="multiple"
                        className="bg-white"
                      >
                        {strategies.map((selection) => (
                          <SelectItem className="bg-white" key={selection.key}>
                            {selection.label}
                          </SelectItem>
                        ))}
                      </Select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="mt-6 flex items-center justify-end gap-x-6">
        <button
          type="submit"
          className="rounded-md bg-green-600 px-3 py-2 text-sm font-semibold text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-green-500 focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 focus-visible:outline-green-600"
        >
          Save and Continue
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>);
};

export default Rafce;


The issue is that nested elements (e.g: demographic) are not showing in the UI - As if I never set the event target value. Also, the Select bitton elements that are supposed to be a simple Yes/No aren't showing

your "handleChange" method will not work with your nested formData structure.  for example, when changing "age", you pass back the event and read the value and name.  unfortunately, the name is "age", and your "handleChange" is only changing the formData property "age", not the nested "demographic.age" which you are displaying.  you could instead have a "handleDemographicChange" method to handle the target, gender, age, and intention props.
const handleDemographicChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormData(prevVals => ({
        ...prevVals,
        demographic: {
            ...prevVals.demographic,
            [name]: value
        }
    }))
}

or something like that.  and similarly for other nested properties.  i would recommend setting up a console.log in a useEffect to display the formData for debug purposes while you work on it, so you can see the structure as the formData changes.  anyway, that is a problem with the nested formData structure that you'll need to address.  i'm not sure about the Select buttons since i don't see where "strategies" are defined.

Thank you. Very insightful - just learned something new
